# Vertex color Animation from houdini to blender 2.8

Tags: export, vertex-colors, alembic

i am trying to export a alembic from houdini to blender. This mesh has a Cd atribute with an animation.

I was able to export a still frame using the ROP alembic node in houdini. I can use the vertex color with no problem.
What i was not able is to export the frame range and viz de vertex color animation inside blender.

[image]

This is my render set up with the still frame. I want the same but with the animation.

How can i make this to work???

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. I can import alembic animations with Cd>Vertex Colors without a problem. Care to share a short abc?

Comment: the problem is that the Cd attrribute inside houdini has an animation. But when i import the vertex color animation to blender i cant  see it

Comment: I understood that, it is clear from the question. How did you export the abc, can you share it?

Comment: I dont know if this is the correct solution.
But i solve it using this modifier and animating the frame value

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W1ox.jpg

Comment: Thats a valid solution. You should post it as a proper answer in the "Answer" field =)