# Getting colored point cloud sequence into Blender

Tags: vertices, color, vertex-colors, alembic, point-clouds

I have motion capture data in the form of a colored point cloud that I would like to get into Blender. The export options from the MoCap program are:

[image]

I have been trying desperately to get the Alembic to work, trying all export combinations. Yet, it always comes into Blender looking like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have found some similar posts:

[Vertex color Animation from houdini to blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176916/vertex-color-animation-from-houdini-to-blender-2-8)

https://developer.blender.org/T53711

[Blender 2.81 doesn't seem to be importing vertex color for .ply](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/blender-2-81-doesnt-seem-to-be-importing-vertex-color-for-ply)

In the last post, "Joe Crozier" comments that there doesn't seem to be a way in Blender to get colors for just points. Is this true?

My other option is to export a sequence of point clouds, perhaps as PLY's and figure out how to render them one frame at a time in Blender. Obviously Alembic seems to be the easiest option.

It's possible to export meshes from this program but they are often of very poor quality as they are based on the points, which can be very sparse.

Comment: I once used this addon that allow to import a sequence of obj, ply etc... https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ  You then can instance cube for example, and render shadeless with emissive, you now could do that using geo node.

Comment: @softyodayoann Thank you. I actually found this add-on which works great as long as you are using Blender 2.81: https://github.com/uhlik/bpy

I was able to animate my point cloud using a sequence of PLYs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to export each cloud as a sequence of PLYs. Then this add-on: https://github.com/uhlik/bpy works for animating it in Blender 2.81.